# Keyboard repeats letter and doesn't type them at all

Tags: windows-iot, keyboard

I have connected a Dell Keyboard to the RPi 3 B, and it keeps repeating letter and sometimes it doesn't even type at all. I have read that its due to insufficient power, but I am using the Adafruit power cable that came with the kit, I have even used another cable that came with another kit.  I am using Win 10 IoT core. Anyone know a fix?

Comment: Have you tried a different keyboard? Or using a powered USB hub to connect the keyboard to the Pi? Is it a wired keyboard? Bluetooth? wireless? Just because the power supply says it will output a certain voltage does not mean that it does or that it is getting to the Pi. If you have a multi-meter you can carefully test the voltage between the 5v and ground pin. What else is connected to the Pi and how?

Comment: @SteveRobillard    Its a USB keyboard. I also have a USB Mouse. I used this http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTIwMFgxNjAw/z/5lsAAOSwA4dWGEfR/$_3.JPG     for a USB Hub. I plugged in the USB Devices and nothing worked.

Comment: I used a multimeter on the pins and I got 5.50-6.15V

Comment: I also discovered that using the SD Card from my other Pi onto the new Pi allows the keyboard to work. The new SD Card that came with the new kit may be corrupted.

Comment: In that case I suggest you answer your own question.

Comment: I must test my theory first.

Comment: I have the same issue. It would be helpful if you actually replied like you promised.

Comment: If you would like a solution, reformatting a SD Card would work. Most likely its corrupt. Worked for me. @Zimano

Comment: Turns out it was my Logitech K120 keyboard! I plugged in a different one lying around the office and it worked.

Comment: @zimano I just bought a Logitech K120 keyboard because I needed one for the Raspberry Pi 3. Guess what--same problem as you.

Comment: Grrr, @Myria That's a bummer >.<

Comment: same issue here with a logitech k120

Comment: same here (logitech k120)

Answer (score 1):

After trying several different USB keyboards, I finally unplugged my new Razer Chroma keyboard from one of my other computers and gave that a try.

The Razer seems to work just fine. I installed the latest Windows IOT core from the Microsoft website to a new 32GB EVO SD card. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 B, NOT the 3BPlus (which does not currently work with IoT).  I had to completely wipe the card destroying all the partitions and create a single new partition.  After that the Windows 10 Core IoT Dashboard worked.

The install computer does not have Wi-Fi, so the first thing after booting up Windows IoT on the PI was to connect to Wi-Fi.  The keyboard problems prevented that, so I spent a couple of days experimenting with various different keyboards, until I discovered the RAZER keyboard works with Windows IoT.  I am using the standard power supply provided by Canakit for the 3BPlus.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. How does you changing your keyboard related to the OP's different keyboard and problem?